# How do you fit an image to a canvas in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to post a picture to a canvas using tkinter. I want the full image to display expand/contract with the canvas window. I then need to be able to put buttons, labels and entries on top of the picture can anyone help with this?

Tried to use `.pack(side = both, expand = True)` but then I can't use `.grid()` to specify where exactly I want to put the buttons etc

```py
class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *pargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *pargs)

        self.image = Image.open("Menu_Display.png")
        self.img_copy= self.image.copy()
        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background = Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        self.background.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = YES)
        self.background.bind('<Configure>', self._resize_image)

    def _resize_image(self,event):

        new_width = event.width
        new_height = event.height

        self.image = self.img_copy.resize((new_width, new_height))

        self.background_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.background.configure(image =  self.background_image)

e = Example(root)
e.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = YES)

root.mainloop()
```

This works perfectly save for the fact that I cant add more objects over it or specify their location

Comment: You can use `.place(...)` for the background image.  Then use either `.pack()` or `.grid()` for others widgets.

Comment: I'll try that now thank you